# Automate Sending Message At Midnight

Tags: automation, text-messaging

I promised my girlfriend I would send her a message tomorrow night (Christmas Eve). She's stuck at an unfortunate party.

The catch is, I don't get cell reception where I will be on Christmas Eve.

I have Google Voice, and frequently use it to message her from online.

I need to automate the sending of a message tomorrow at midnight. I can just pretype the message, I just need to send it at the right time while I am away from my computer.

I can sort of use AutoHotKey, but I couldn't figure out a way to send a Click at a specific time.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using task scheduler to run a autohotkey task, since you seem to have the rest worked out?